# Need to run VBscripts not edit them

Tags: vbscript

I have installed an editor that changed the default behavior for *.vbs files. Now when I attempt to run a *.vbs file that is a driver update it will not run. How do I reset to the default windows application for *.vbs files. I understand how to modify default application for file types, but Windows Script Host does not come up as one of those options

Answer (score 0):

Right click any *.vbs file, and select 'open with', upon doing that, click the browse button, and navigate to 'C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe', then click 'OK' and 'Apply' and you're done.

If that fails to work, download and run the file located [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/169011d1312707514-default-file-type-associations-restore-default_vbs.reg). It's a registry file that should restore the default settings for .vbs extension. Reported to be that same in Win8 as Win7. if you're unsure about running it, you can always open it in notepad to see which registries it changes. Once you have downloaded it, right click and select 'Merge'. Once you have done that, log off and back on or restart to apply the changes

Comment: I have tried that and I am not sure if it is a Win8.1 thing or what but after I select wscript.exe as the new default for that file extension nothing happens.